# dlls missing after publishing .NET Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My web project use `.NET Framework 4.7.2` and use some references like

- `System.IO`
- `System.Net`
- `System.Net.Http`
- `System.Net.Http.Formatting`

My project works perfectly in local. 
However, when I publish my web project on a target directory (for online), and look what it contains in `/bin/` :

- `System.IO` *is missing*
- `System.Net` is present
- `System.Net.Http` *is missing*
- `System.Net.Http.Formatting`is present

Therefore, when I use my website, I get the obvious error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

All references have `Copy Local = True` in `Properties` but some dll are always ignored. If i copy the dlls from local directory to target directory i get the error `Server Error in '/' Application. Cannot load a reference assembly for execution. Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.` [Exactly the same problem as this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765783/net-4-6-website-not-loading-reference-assemblies-correctly) 
 However the delete/rebuild solution, or adding compilation options solution, doesn't work for me

What do I need to do to get these missing dlls to the destination folder?

Comment: Check your nuget manifest

Comment: Yes? `System.IO` and `System.Net.Http` packages are installed

Comment: Is this one project or separate projects? If say you have the web app, then separate projects for say Data, Model etc, there could be reference diff between them

Comment: One solution using double projects. The .NET Web + source of one dll (not using  `System.Net.Http` but using `System.IO`)

Comment: We had a similar issue recently and it was due to version of dlls being different from one project to the other being referenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Solution Explorer on VS, open references tree, right click on the library(dll) and select properties on the menu. On properties box **Copy Local** should be **True**

Comment: As indicated in the original post, it's done. All references have `Copy Local = True` But it doesn't work.

Comment: `System.IO` and `System.Net.Http` packages are installed  with the last version

Comment: One of your dlls is not updated and that causes the issue. Please make sure all the libraries are updated.It very common that libraries which are not compatible work fine in debug mode but give an error in release mode. And when you publish you are usually in release mode. See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Also make sure the libraries are compatible with .net version you are using.

Comment: Works in local. The .NET Framework version can change after publishing ?

Comment: No, as long as server support the version you used.  You don't need to install System.IO and System.Net.Http . They are parts of .net framework. maybe by installing the new packages, you made them incompatible with your project .net version